# Limit OG available on registration form

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I want to let my user to request membership to an OG through the user registration form (they should select the company you belong too). I found how to

I have two content type set as OG (company and committee). When I enable group audience selection in the registration form all my OG are displayed. I want to display only value related to the company OG.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate.

You should create registrationlinks like this for it to work auto: /user/register?og_user_node=X where X is the groupid.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this setting since I decided to use a different process where user register and request membership in two steps.